# Twitter2QGIS plugin error "EOF occurred in violation of protocol"

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, error, twitter

I installed `twitter2qgis` plugin and also tweepy through pip manually and then, I put access token etc value from my developer twitter account and when I apply I get this error:

[image: Error]

And this is written in it:

> SSLError: [Errno 8] _ssl.c:504: EOF occurred in violation of protocol Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/Users/HAMMAD AHMAD/.qgis2/python/plugins\geotweet\geotweet.py", line 321, in run stream.filter(track=keywords) File "C:\Users\HAMMAD AHMAD\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 445, in filter self._start(async) File "C:\Users\HAMMAD AHMAD\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 361, in _start self._run() File "C:\Users\HAMMAD AHMAD\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 294, in _run raise exception SSLError: [Errno 8] _ssl.c:504: EOF occurred in violation of protocol
>
> Python version: 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] QGIS version: 2.18.1 Las Palmas, 3e73840
>
> Python Path: C:/PROGRA~1/QGISLA~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing C:/PROGRA~1/QGISLA~1/apps/qgis/./python C:/Users/HAMMAD AHMAD/.qgis2/python C:/Users/HAMMAD AHMAD/.qgis2/python/plugins C:/PROGRA~1/QGISLA~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLA~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-1.3.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLA~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLA~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\tornado-4.0.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLA~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\backports.ssl_match_hostname-3.4.0.2-py2.7.egg C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLA~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\certifi-14.05.14-py2.7.egg C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\python.exe C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLA~1\bin\python27.zip C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLA~1\apps\Python27\DLLs C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLA~1\apps\Python27\lib C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLA~1\apps\Python27\lib\plat-win C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLA~1\apps\Python27\lib\lib-tk C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLA~1\bin C:\Users\HAMMAD AHMAD\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLA~1\apps\Python27 C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLA~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLA~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLA~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\jinja2-2.7.2-py2.7.egg C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLA~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\markupsafe-0.23-py2.7-win-amd64.egg C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLA~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytz-2012j-py2.7.egg C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLA~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32 C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLA~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLA~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLA~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win-amd64.egg C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLA~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLA~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd-0.9.2-py2.7.egg C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLA~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwt-0.7.5-py2.7.egg C:/Users/HAMMAD AHMAD/.qgis2//python